# How to change the direction of a group sprite based on a condition in Phaser 3

Tags: game-development, phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser 3 and tried doing this:

```
class Bee extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
    constructor(config) {
        super(config.scene, config.x, config.y, 'bee');
        config.scene.add.existing(this);
        config.scene.physics.add.existing(this);

        this.initial = [config.x, config.y];
        this.x = config.x;
        this.y = config.y;
        this.speed = 5;
    }

    preUpdate() {
        if  (this.y < this.initial[1] - 100) {
            this.speed *= -1;
        }
        if (this.y > this.initial[1] + 100) {
            this.speed *= -1;
        }

        this.y += this.speed;
        this.setY(this.y);
    }
}
```

I want a Bee object to move down 100 px then move up and then repeat, but it doesn't seem to work.

In my scene I created a object:

```
bees = this.physics.add.group();

let bee = new Bee({scene:scene, x: 100, y:200})
bee.setScale(0.5);
bee.allowGravity = false;
bees.add(bee);
```

I'll have multiple Bee sprites in the game.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the up and down movement with a simple **tween** (https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tweens.Tween.html).
A tween changes/moves the selected property *(or multiple properties)* between a starting and an end position. In your case, I would use it to change the `y` property of the bee *physic body velocity*.

> *You can do alot with a **tween**, without the need to calculate speed, next position and so on. You just have to tweak the properties of the tween config, to get the desired movement/animation.*

**Here a working example:**
*(**Update:** Now with a few bees in the group and an 'offset' for the flight pattern)*

```js
class Bee extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
    constructor(config) {
        super(config.scene, config.x, config.y, 'bee');
        config.scene.add.existing(this);
        config.scene.physics.add.existing(this);

        this.x = config.x;
        this.y = config.y;
        
       config.scene.tweens.add({
            targets: this.body.velocity,
            y: { from: -100, to: 100  },
            ease: Phaser.Math.Easing.Quadratic.InOut,
            yoyo: true,
            repeat: -1,
            duraton: 1000,
            // just to create a interesting offset for the example
            delay: Phaser.Math.Between(0,6) * 200
        });
    }
}

function create(){

    let bees = this.physics.add.group();

    for(let i=0; i < 10 ; i++){
      let bee = new Bee({scene: this, 
          x: i * -100 , 
          y: 50 });       
      bees.add(bee);
    }     
    bees.setVelocity(100,0)
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
      physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
    },
    scene: {
      create
    }
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. But there's a small issue. The bee sprite keeps falling few pixels in each iteration. Eventually it gets out of the screen. I think it's because of gravity. Can you please help me to turn off gravity for this bee object

Comment: thanks. I dit it this way : ```let bees = this.physics.add.group({allowGravity:false});```

Comment: @PrajjwalPathak is everything solved or do you need some more help with the answer?

Comment: thanks but i solved it